# How do I assign the value of a refcursor to a variable in PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This stored procedure call returns a single varchar2 type value. The issue is that it comes back in a refcursor. I need to get the ID value and assign it to a variable instead of printing it to the console.

```
var r refcursor;
DECLARE    
BEGIN
P_PACKAGE.INSERT_INVOICE(
    IN_INVOICE_TYPE             => L_INVOICE.INVOICE_TYPE,
    OUTPUT => :R);
END;
/
print r;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't define the REFCURSOR in SQL*Plus as you've shown it. Assuming that your `REFCURSOR` was opened with a statement similar to

```
SELECT ID
  FROM SOME_TABLE
  WHERE SOMEFIELD = some_value
```

then your PL/SQL code should look something like

```
DECLARE    
  aString   VARCHAR2(2000);
  rc        SYS_REFCURSOR;
BEGIN
  P_PACKAGE.INSERT_INVOICE(
      IN_INVOICE_TYPE             => L_INVOICE.INVOICE_TYPE,
      OUTPUT => rc);

  FETCH rc
    INTO aString;

  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('aString = ''' || aString || '''');
END;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but can you explain why this section no longer has a colon OUTPUT => rc);? I needed to have a line like this: OUTPUT => :R);  or else the print statement at the end doesn't return anything

Comment: var r refcursor;
O_INVOICE_ID Z_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID%TYPE;
DECLARE    
BEGIN
P_PACKAGE.INSERT_INVOICE(
    IN_INVOICE_TYPE             => L_INVOICE.INVOICE_TYPE,
    OUTPUT => R);

    FETCH r INTO O_INVOICE_ID;
END;
/
print O_INVOICE_ID;

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. The comment above compile but doesn't print any output

Comment: This was the correct answer. I didn't understand it entirely at first. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly as you said - you need to assign it to a variable. Here's an example based on Scott's schema.

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_rc (par_deptno in number, par_rc out sys_refcursor)
  2  is
  3  begin
  4    open par_rc for select ename, sal
  5      from emp
  6      where deptno = par_deptno;
  7  end;
  8  /

Procedure created.
```

Let's test it; pay attention to lines #4, 5 (declaration of variables) and #10 (fetch into those variables):

```
SQL> declare
  2    l_rc sys_refcursor;
  3    -- declare variables which will get values returned by refcursor
  4    l_ename  emp.ename%type;
  5    l_sal    emp.sal%type;
  6  begin
  7    p_rc(10, l_rc);
  8
  9    loop
 10      fetch l_rc into l_ename, l_sal;
 11      exit when l_rc%notfound;
 12      dbms_output.put_line(rpad(l_ename, 10, ' ') ||': '|| l_sal);
 13    end loop;
 14  end;
 15  /
CLARK     : 2450
KING      : 5001
MILLER    : 1300

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: DECLARE              
r sys_refcursor;

O_INVOICE_ID Z_INVOICE.INVOICE_ID%TYPE;

BEGIN
P_PACKAGE.INSERT_INVOICE(
    IN_INVOICE_TYPE             => L_INVOICE.INVOICE_TYPE,
    OUTPUT => R);
    loop
      fetch r into O_INVOICE_ID;
      exit when r%notfound;
       end loop;
END;
/

Comment: Compiles successfully but there's no output. 
I'm trying to get the result fromt the cursor (It'll always be one varchar2 value)
and then run a select. 

select * from Z_INVOICE where invoice_id = o_invoice_id;

This is currently failing:

ORA-06550: line 34, column 5:
PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:

Comment: Sorry for the formatting, not sure how to format comments. CTRL + K doesn't work for me

Comment: If there's no output, make sure you enabled it. In SQL*Plus or SQL Developer, run `set serveroutput on`. As of PLS-00428 error - you can't run SELECT without an INTO clause in PL/SQL.